# Report generator for C++/Qt (Windows)

Tags: c++, qt, pdf, report

I have a program un C++/Qt written for Windows, which prints some graphs in pdf format and some other data in HTML.

I need to print all together into a single PDF, a single-file report.

I have looked for some libraries similar to Crystal reports, but I just find paid ones and I need a free open-source solution. I finally found [RTK reports](http://reports.sourceforge.net/index.php) but it looks to run only with UNIX.

Any library or different solution for my needs?

Comment: Have a look at KD Reports: http://www.kdab.com/kdab-products/kd-reports/

Comment: Already did, but I asked for a free one

Comment: KDReports is also available under GPL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out what Qt has built into it in versions 4.7 & 4.8.  From [Qt 4.8: Printing with Qt](http://doc.trolltech.com/main-snapshot/printing.html), there is this little tidbit "Qt's printing system also enables PostScript and PDF files to be generated...."  The [QPrinter class](http://doc.trolltech.com/main-snapshot/qprinter.html) supports several different [Output Formats](http://doc.trolltech.com/main-snapshot/qprinter.html#OutputFormat-enum), including PDF.

Disclaimer: I haven't played with this part of Qt, so YMMV.